# chroot: can't resolve domain names

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, chroot

i can't resolve domain names in chrooted environment - in the normal shell it works fine.

i'm using plesk 11.5 and my chroot environment contains the following:
https://gist.github.com/xarem/5356ca94367ea8666e23

my resolv.conf:

```
search company.ch
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

my nsswitch.conf:

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

i tried to port nslookup into the chrooted env, but that didn't work and i can't find a solution for this:

```
usr@srv:/$ nslookup google.com                                  
(null): dst_lib_init: openssl failure
```

Can someone help me? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

If apt-get is not available in the jail it's also possible by just copying the openssl libs into the chroot jail.

```
cp -R /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openssl-1.0.0 /<chroot>/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/
```

Remember to set permissions correctly.

Comment: It would be better to explain why you're writing about apt-get here.  I couldn't understand your answer if not by reading the other answer provided.  Please make your answer standalone or explicitly refering to the other answer if you want to credit it or you think it is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Please install the OpenSSL package, using `sudo apt-get install openssl`. Then try it again.

Comment: Ok, I modified it.